# How to group and count in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query which extracts the total number of non-deleted messages sent to their friends. Here is a screenshot of the table structures:

[image]

The output result that I am trying to achieve is as below:

```
 id          messages_count
 ---------------------------
 1            4562
 2            7255
```

Here is the query that I have tried so far:

```
SELECT u.id, count( CASE WHEN m.is_deleted = false THEN m.is_deleted END ) as messages_count
FROM users u
inner join messages m on u.id = m.to_id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something along the lines of this?

```
SELECT u.id, count( m ) as messages_count
FROM users u
inner join messages m on u.id = m.to_id and m.is_deleted = false
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id;
```

Comment: Yes I've tried that but ID 4 and ID 5 gave the wrong messages_count value. It should be 0 for both of ID 4 and 5

Comment: As opposed to what, @bingaloman?  This is a slightly weird way to do it, but it's not clear from anything presented in the question why it wouldn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IS` keyword in `WHERE` clause. Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, count( m.id ) as messages_count
FROM users u
INNER JOIN messages m on u.id = m.to_id
WHERE m.is_deleted is FALSE
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides Jake White's answer, you can also use sum in this way:

```
SELECT u.id,
   sum( CASE WHEN m.is_deleted = false THEN 1 else 0 END ) as messages_count
FROM users u
inner join messages m on u.id = m.to_id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id;
```

it should be clear -- if not deleted, contribute to sum, else not.